# Is there any way to run a portion of a large query on bigquery when the free quota doesn't allow it?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In other words I have this but it says quota is exceeded since 2.3tb should be processed when run:

```
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.contents` 
WHERE content like "%neuralnetwork%"
LIMIT 5000
```

So is there a way to query the same table but say 10% of it or so? 10x

Comment: There is a sample table right next to that one, which is way smaller (more outdated tho)

Comment: reduce unwanted columns, use a column-list rather than a `*`

Comment: @CavinDsouza OK i'll try that....

Comment: @FelipeHoffa any idea if the sample contains at least significant portion of the other table? I don't mind even year outdated for as long as it has some 10-20% or more of the big table

Comment: Usually a 2.3 Tb table would be partitioned.  Just query one partition.

Comment: As I can see here, this specific public table doesn't have any partitions. In your case, the only way for reducing the amount of data queried is selecting specific columns instead of all the columns